# Can't open page through django

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

I'am trying to make some simple button for sending text and work with it, but after press button, i have a 404 error.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5niauorf5gccqp7/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-10-24%2015.08.07.png?dl=0

My project's urls file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('home.urls')),
    url(r'^kanji_analyzer/$', include('kanji_analyzer.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My app's url file is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.start_kanji, name='start_kanji'),
    url(r'^analyze/$', views.send_text),
```

My view's:

```
def start_kanji(request):
    t = get_template('kanji_analyzer/main.html')
    html = t.render(Context())
    return HttpResponse(html)


def send_text(request):
    t = get_template('kanji_analyzer/show_results.html')
    html = t.render(Context())
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

and html templates:

main.html

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{{% block body %}
<h1 align="center">Analyzed text</h1>
    <form action="analyze" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Analyze">
    </form>


<div class=page>
    {% include "kanji_analyzer/show_results.html" %}
</div>
{% endblock %}}
```

and show_results.html

```
{% block results %}
    <h1 align="center">Results</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `$` sign:

```
url(r'^kanji_analyzer/', include('kanji_analyzer.urls')),
```